# Platform update for cordova ios

Tags: cordova, cordova-ios

I am currently working a project that was creating with cordova 6.5, and is using the ios platform 4.2.1, I am looking to update to the latest version of the ios platform 4.5.4, but simply removing the platform and installing the new platform is resulting in a compile error with error code 65. Is there something more to the platform upgrade process then simply uninstalling the old platform and installing the new? I have tried compiling with both xcode 8.3.3 and 9.2

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/renaumacmini/desktop/powerbrick/power-brick-app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,Argus System.xcworkspace,-scheme,Argus System,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,Argus System.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/renaumacmini/desktop/powerbrick/power-brick-app/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/renaumacmini/desktop/powerbrick/power-brick-app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Comment: Removing and adding the platform is a valid way to upgrade.  However, upgrades are sometimes breaking...  You'll have to look at your process as it's likely something you were doing before is no longer the correct way on the updated version.

Comment: That's what i expected, the problem being I was hired to replace the original developer who I never met so, it's like a scavenger hunt through the code

Comment: Cordova and XCode updates have both been frequent causes of headaches for me when building for iOS.  Android problems are few and far between, but iOS, argh.